# Excel - product list price update, based on a bigger list

Tags: excel, list, price

i tried to find a solution but wasn't lucky. Im trying to update a prices for a list of 1400+ products, but i have to find those new prices on bigger list of 3000+ products. I have indexes (indices?) in both columns.

I've already tried few things like IF there index D is in column I then give me "OK"

**=IF(COUNTIF(I$2:I$3000;D2)=1;"OK";"NOK")**

This gives me an information that i have on "my list" an index that is also on "new" list with new prices. But this is not helpful at all since i dunno how to use those "OK" to copy new prices.

I've tried to use INDEX MATCH and VLOOKUP, neither worked, as you can see clearly im not an expert in Excel.

**What ineed is:**

**If there is 'true' value (or OK) for my IF function, then copy new price (cell previous to one with new indexes).**

Or something else, if it works of course.

Sorry for my terrible english.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRb9h.jpg)

Comment: You can use VLookup or Index/Match to find the prices. But it depends on your data layout on the sheet. Show us how your data is arranged on the sheet.

Comment: EDITED, added a picture + some whining about using Index/Match & Vlookup without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$3000,MATCH(D2,$I$2:$I$3000,0)),"NOK")
```

and copy it down.

If you use a semicolon instead of a comma in excel formulas as per your regional settings, change the suggested formula to this...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$3000;MATCH(D2;$I$2:$I$3000;0));"NOK")
```

Comment: There is some kind of error. I can give you a screenshot of error itself but its all in polish so you probably wont understand any of it. 
[image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gckEm.jpg

Comment: Replace comma (,) I used in the formula with a semi-colon (;) and the formula will work fine.

Comment: You're welcome Pejot88! Glad it worked. Please take a moment to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: I did :) if it is possible, please edit your answer and put this comment about semi-colon into that marked answer :) thanks again!